# If $g: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ with $\Delta(g)=\Delta(f)=2 \pi u$ and $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z)-g(z)=0.$ Then $g=f.$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $u: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a smooth function with compact support. Let $f=2 \pi \log * u $ where $*$ denotes the convolution product. (i.e $\int \log \vert y \vert u(x-y)d \mu_{y}.$) If $g: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a smooth function on $\mathbb{C}$ with $\Delta(g)=\Delta(f)=2 \pi u$ and $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z)-g(z)=0.$ Then $g=f.$

Comment: $f-g$ is a bounded (follows from the limit of $z \to \infty$ being zero and the function being continuous) harmonic function on $\mathbb R^2$, thus constant. From your limit you get that the constant is zero.

Comment: Ok yes you're right. $f-g$ is constant because of Lioville's theorem.  Thank you